# How to create an event subscription with enpoint type Azure Function using the CLI?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cli

Trying to create an event subscription using the CLI.

Using the portal, there are seven different endpoint types:

- Azure Function
- Web Hook
- Storage Queues
- Event Hubs
- Hybrid Connections
- Service Bus Queue
- Service Bus Topic

Using the CLI, at least in the documentation, only three are available:

- eventhub
- hybridconnection
- servicebusqueue
- storagequeue
- webhook

How to create an event subscription pointing to an Azure Function **like it is done in the portal**? I know that as a workaround I can use the function as a WebHook, but it is not the same.

Az version:

```
$ az --version
azure-cli                          2.7.0

command-modules-nspkg              2.0.3
core                               2.7.0
nspkg                              3.0.4
telemetry                          1.0.4

Extensions:
interactive                        0.4.4

Python location '/opt/az/bin/python3'
Extensions directory '/home/angelcc/.azure/cliextensions'

Python (Linux) 3.6.10 (default, May 29 2020, 08:10:59) 
[GCC 9.3.0]

Legal docs and information: aka.ms/AzureCliLegal


Your CLI is up-to-date.

Please let us know how we are doing: https://aka.ms/clihats
and let us know if you're interested in trying out our newest features: https://aka.ms/CLIUXstudy
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the following example:

```
  az eventgrid event-subscription create --name myName \
      --source-resource-id "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/myRG/providers/Microsoft.EventGrid/topics/myTopic" \
      --endpoint-type AzureFunction \
      --endpoint "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/myRG1/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/myFncApp/functions/myEventGridTrigger"
```

**UPDATE:**

In the case of avoiding the *eventgrid* extension, we can use a native access to the AEG service such as [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/eventgrid/version2020-04-01-preview/eventsubscriptions/createorupdate).

The following is the above example using the *az rest*:

```
az rest --method PUT \
  --url "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/myRG/providers/Microsoft.EventGrid/topics/myTopic/providers/Microsoft.EventGrid/eventSubscriptions/myName?api-version=2020-04-01-preview" \
  --body "{\"properties\":{\"destination\":{\"endpointType\":\"AzureFunction\",\"properties\":{\"resourceId\":\"/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/myRG1/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/myFncApp/functions/myEventGridTrigger\"}}}}"
```

Comment: That was my first try. :)
az eventgrid event-subscription create: 'AzureFunction' is not a valid value for '--endpoint-type'. See 'az eventgrid event-subscription create --help'.
And in the help, only the list of options that I shared in the question. The same lucky using lower cases.

Comment: This example has been made in my portal *Cloud Shell* and its working. I can see the documents https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/eventgrid/event-subscription?view=azure-cli-latest#az-eventgrid-event-subscription-create is not updated, but *az eventgrid event-subscription create --help* is showing: The type of the destination endpoint.  Allowed values: azurefunction, eventhub,                                          hybridconnection, servicebusqueue, servicebustopic, storagequeue, webhook.                                                    Default: webhook.

Comment: I'm using azure-cli 2.7.0, that it is the last version  available to download. I'm going to check using the Cloud shell.

Comment: The same error using the Cloud shell. Also, `--help` does not show azurefunction as an option. Which version are you using?

Comment: the following is my: roman@Azure:~$ az version
{
  "azure-cli": "2.7.0",
  "azure-cli-command-modules-nspkg": "2.0.3",
  "azure-cli-core": "2.7.0",
  "azure-cli-nspkg": "3.0.4",
  "azure-cli-telemetry": "1.0.4",
  "extensions": {
    "azure-cli-iot-ext": "0.6.1",
    "eventgrid": "0.4.4"
  }
}

Comment: All look exactly like my version setup, except the list of extensions. Maybe it is part of `azure-cli-iot-ext` or `eventgrid`?

Comment: **Confirmed!!**. It is part of the `eventgrid` extension, so officially is not supported.
To check it, I installed the extension and execute the `--help`

Comment: If you modify the response to clarify that the `eventgrid extension` is necessary, so the option is a `preview` at the moment, I will check the response as the right one. ;)

Comment: The output message: *The behavior of this command has been altered by the following extension: eventgrid*

Comment: Yes, this message is because the extension overwrites the default behavior adding more features and options.  But i remember  to read in the extension documentation that is is a preview.

Comment: Yes, it is a preview: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/azure-cli-extensions-list?view=azure-cli-latest